# jQuery avoid double clone

Tags: jquery, slider, clone

I have this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6oocxsmn/)，when I click add button for many times, and the edit button over than two times, the slider didn't show the correct time when in edit mode, and double clone the slider, how to fix it?

```js
loadslides();

        function loadslides(){
        var sliders = $('.slider');
        sliders.each(function(){
            $(this).slider({
            range: true,
            min: 0,
            max: 1440,
            step: 60,
            values: [400, 920],
                    
            slide: function (e, ui) {
                var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
                var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);

                if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
                if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
                if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
                if (hours1 < 10) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
                if (hours1 == 24) {
                    hours1 = "23";
                    minutes1 = "59";
                }

                $(this).closest('div').siblings().find('.time1').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

                var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
                var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

                if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
                if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
                if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
                if (hours2 < 10) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
                if (hours2 == 24) {
                    hours2 = "23";
                    minutes2 = "59";
                }

                $(this).closest('div').siblings().find('.time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
            }
        });
        });
        }
        $('#add').click(function() {
            var Time = $('.time1').html() + ' - ' + $('.time2').html();
            
            var row = '<tr class="myRows">'
                    + '<td class="rowTime">' + Time + '</td>'
                    + '<td><div><button type="button" class="edit">Edit</button></div></td>'
                    + '</tr>';

            $(row).insertAfter($("#form > tbody > tr:last"));
            $(".slider").slider('values', [400, 920]);
            $('.time1').text('07:00');
            $('.time2').text('15:00');
        });

        $('#form').on('click','.edit',function() {
            var $row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var rowTime = $row.find('.rowTime');
            var times = rowTime.text();
            rowTime.html($('.slider').clone());
            rowTime.each(function() {
                $(this).html();
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sliderTime"> 
    <span class="time1">07:00</span> - <span class="time2">15:00</span>
</div>
<div class="slider"></div>
    <button type="button" id="add">Add</button>
<table id="form">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Table Rules</th>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This code is what I've tried... I'm not familiar with js > <

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are adding elements with the "slider" class to your dom when you click add or edit. 
this line of code $('.slider').clone() will clone of the slider you added, you want to clone only the big one on top.

you need to add an id to the main slider

```
<div class="slider" id="main-slider"></div>
```

and clone only that one

```
rowTime.html($('#main-slider').clone());
```

also this does nothing

```
rowTime.each(function() {
   $(this).html();
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/6oocxsmn/3/